# Newly created audio element in inactive tab doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have web based audio player and want to preload next track while current is playing.
So I create new audio object `prefetch = new Audio(url)` and when it is time to switch I just swap current audio with preloaded one and trigger `.play()`.

But it doesn't always work when tab is not active. Sometimes when it is time to swap I found prefetched object with `networkState == 3 (NETWORK_NO_SOURCE)` and `readyState = 0 (HAVE_NOTHING)`.

When I switch back to the tab - it immediately starts to playing.

I beleive it caused by async resource selection algorithm and browser optmiziations, but not sure how to make it work.

(Mostly reproducible in Safari).

Answer (score 0):

It's because browser optimizations. Browser reduce resources allocated to inactive tab, that's why you JS is working lowly or may not work at all.

You can try using [WebWorker](https://robertnyman.com/2010/03/25/using-html5-web-workers-to-have-background-computational-power/) ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)) that has no limits when tab goes inactive.

[Check this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12522580/1346234)

Comment: Yes, I understand, but is there any way to force play without web workers?